# Installed Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET Web API - An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AccountController'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I previously used Unity dependency injection from the tutorial [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

However I wanted to use `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` so I installed [Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET Web API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.AspNet.WebApi).

However this gave me an error I did not previously have in `AccountController`. From what I can tell it has something to do with the IUserStore but what I don't understand is why this error occurs after installing this NuGet. Unity has been installed and used before and I did not have to register types for `AccountController`.

UnityConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<DbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

    container.RegisterType<IArticleRepository, ArticleRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<ISupplierRepository, SupplierRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<ICampaignRepository, CampaignRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
}
```

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error
>   occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public
>   constructor.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Resolution of the dependency
>   failed, type = \"Project.Sales.Web.Controllers.AccountController\",
>   name = \"(none)\".\r\nException occurred while: while
>   resolving.\r\nException is: InvalidOperationException - The current
>   type,
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`2[HiQ.Repository.EntityFramework.Identity.BaseApplicationUser,System.Int32],
>   is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\nAt the
>   time of the exception, the container was:\r\n\r\n Resolving
>   Project.Sales.Web.Controllers.AccountController,(none)\r\n Resolving
>   parameter \"userManager\" of constructor
>   Project.Sales.Web.Controllers.AccountController(Project.Sales.Web.ApplicationUserManager
>   userManager,
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.ISecureDataFormat`1[[Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket,
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] accessTokenFormat)\r\n Resolving
>   Project.Sales.Web.ApplicationUserManager,(none)\r\n Resolving
>   parameter \"store\" of constructor
>   Project.Sales.Web.ApplicationUserManager(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`2[[HiQ.Repository.EntityFramework.Identity.BaseApplicationUser,
>   HiQ.Repository.EntityFramework, Version=0.1.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] store)\r\n
>   Resolving
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`2[HiQ.Repository.EntityFramework.Identity.BaseApplicationUser,System.Int32],(none)\r\n","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException","StackTrace":"
>   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name,
>   ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve(IUnityContainer
>   container, Type t, ResolverOverride[] overrides)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver.SharedDependencyScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has
>   occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The current type,
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`2[HiQ.Repository.EntityFramework.Identity.BaseApplicationUser,System.Int32],
>   is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForAttemptingToConstructInterface(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey
>   newBuildKey)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey
>   newBuildKey)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)"}}}

Comment: if the `AccountController` receives a parameter of type `IUserStore` then you will have to register a implementation for this type too, or the unity will not be able to make an instance of the controller.

Comment: Please stop using Unity for new projects. Unity is dead https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/issues. There will be no more releases for Unity. No bug fixes. No support.

Comment: @NightOwl888 What do you recommend instead?

Comment: @Ogglas - Pick [one of the ~35](https://github.com/danielpalme/IocPerformance) other ones. If you want something officially supported from MS, there is [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection), but I can't attest to how good it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original problem for this was that Unity tried to call the constructor with two parameters:

```
public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
    ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
}
```

By adding the following line telling Unity to call the parameterless constructor everything worked again.

```
container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
```